# Special sequence in R

Tags: r, seq, rep

I would like to create the follow sequence without a loop for a value *d* greater equal 1:

`c(d:2, d:3, d:4, ..., d:(d-1), d)`

Is this possible?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you mean c(1:1, 1:2, ...1:d)? Because assume d equals 4, then you'd get c(4:2, 4:3, 4:4 and so on), but you probably want (1:2, 1:3, 1:4)? So can you share teh expected outcome for a certain d value, e.g. 4 or 5?

Comment: `lapply(2:d, function(x) seq(d, x))`

Answer (score 0):

If you want from 1 to d

```
sapply(1:d,function(x){seq(x,d)})
```

if you want from d to 1

```
sapply(1:d,function(x){seq(d,x)})
```